# JBL 460T connected to PC but mic not working windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, microphone, headphones

Hi I'm using windows 10 Pro on a PC which I built myself. My bluetooth headphone gets connected and also stereo audio works fine. But when it comes to hands free I do not get any audio nor does the mic work. Also there is no option for mic if using stereo. Please help me I want to use mic badly.

Comment: related, idk if dupe or not - https://superuser.com/questions/930251/possible-to-use-bluetooth-headset-in-stereo-mode-with-mic?rq=1

Comment: hands free is also fine but it does not even work