# Possible to use Bluetooth 5.0 headset in high quality stereo mode with mic simultaneously? (2021)

Tags: audio, bluetooth, microphone

For the past couple of years I was trying to use my Bluetooth headset (Sony MDR1000x) as a gaming headset, but I wouldn't get Stereo sound while the mic was activated (duplex audio apparently is what it is called). I found many people had the same problem, and it has been discussed multiple times that it was not possible. I found this question from 2017 ([Possible to use Bluetooth headset in Stereo mode with Mic?](https://superuser.com/questions/930251/possible-to-use-bluetooth-headset-in-stereo-mode-with-mic)) that clarifies the situation and the reasons, including the top voted answer which includes a partial solution that would work on some devices with aptX.

But... it is 4 years later and I want to buy a new Bluetooth over-ear noise-cancelling headset. Technology has supposedly come a long way now, and we have Bluetooth 5.0, updated versions of codecs, etc. My question is if this situation has been solved, and if I get Bluetooth 5.0 connectivity with a new headset, this problem will be gone or will I still find some problem with headsets? Is there anything specific I should look for (a feature or spec) on a device that would allow this duplex high-quality audio/voice?

Comment: There has been no significant change or improvement to Bluetooth in this regard. You *might* find a headset that can, but probably it will be the same as before. Bluetooth 5 adds nothing new in this regard.